# How to consume https wsdl in C# using certificate

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, https

Please help me on how to consume a webservice having https in c#. How should I use the certificates for https.

Any leads appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials in the internet, just google it. "how to consume web service c#"

Comment: Hi @SachithWickramaarachchi I have checked but none of them are giving how to consume https service along with certificate. Please help if you find any. TIA